# How to define "Map" AttributeType in dynamo db?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am new in **aws dynamo db**. I [have read](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html) that we can set `M` type of attributeValue in schema of dynamo db.

But when I execute the code below

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'product',
    KeySchema: [
        {
            AttributeName: 'productType',
            KeyType: 'HASH'
        },
         {
            AttributeName: 'manufacturer',
            KeyType: 'SORT'
        }
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [
        {
            AttributeName: 'productType',
            AttributeType: 'S'
        },
         {
            AttributeName: 'manufacturer',
            AttributeType: 'M'
        }
    ],
     ProvisionedThroughput: {
        ReadCapacityUnits: 1, 
        WriteCapacityUnits: 1, 
    }

};
dynamodb.createTable(params, function(err, data) {
   console.log(err, data);

});
```

It keeps throwing error  `{"message":"Member must satisfy enum value set: [B, N, S]","code":"ValidationException","time":"2018-02-07T11:20:12.930Z","statusCode":400,"retryable":false}`

But the above link says that there is an attribute of type Map available. Can someone explain me how can I achieve Map in dynamo db.

Answer (score 31):

When you create a dynamodb table, or add an index to it, you can only define the attributes for the indexes. In other words, you can only define the attributes used for a partition key or sort key. like you are doing in your example. But the only attribute types that are valid for keys are S (string), N (number), and B (binary). Maps are not valid attribute types for either partition or sort keys, so you can't use them when defining your table or index.

DynamoDB is schema-less. You don't define any attributes other than the ones for the index keys at table creation. If you want a map in your table, you simply insert one when you put or update items.

Comment: What about defining an attribute in a Map as an index?

Comment: @Purefan - only scalar types can be in index.

Answer (score 2):

To insert Map type you should format data like below,

```js
"M": {"Name": {"S": "Joe"}, "Age": {"N": "35"}}
```

Please find the screenshot from AWS documentation,

[image]

In this example, "M" means Map data type,  "Name" is the key "S" (string) is the datatype of that key and value is "Joe" and so on

Also, read documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html)

Comment: I understand that to insert data I have to write object in the above format ("M": {"Name": {"S": "Joe"}, "Age": {"N": "35"}}) but before that I have to create table and I got error while creating table, that's what my question is.

Comment: Again if I store data like ("M": {"Name": {"S": "Joe"}, "Age": {"N": "35"}})  then after scan table the data I got in same format and if I want to fetch "Joe" then I have to write "data.M.Name.S", why I cant save just plain object like {Name: "Joe", Age: "35"}?

Answer (score 2):

This is basically the drawback of DynamoDB , vs say MongoDB or couchbase . The other NoSQL Dbs can let you have documents of any shape and index any attribute no matter how deep it is. In DD , you don't have this flexibility - top level attributes which are indexable must be scalar . This is the trade off for speed.

Answer (score 1):

You can look [here for attribute definitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeDefinition.html), the only allowed values are `B, N, S`.

You should use strings to define your map.

Answer (score 0):

[The AttributeDefinition property type represents an attribute for describing the key schema for a DynamoDB table and indexes.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-dynamodb-attributedef.html) Only two attributes are mandatory when creating a table, a partition key and sort key if available. If you intended  to use the `manufacturer` key as an index, please note that it is an invalid operation as dynamodb only supports scalar data types.

**tl;dr** Therefore, when creating the table, you should omit the "non-key/index" attributes, which in your case is the `manufacturer` key.